# Handling Back button on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have 2 pages in my Windows Phone 8.1 app.

The 1st page displays 9 image buttons. Its purpose is to allow the User to enter their 4 digit PIN to proceed to the next screen.

Scenario:

the User enters PIN and goes to 2nd screen.

I go to bed.

i wake up.

I go to my mobile.

I am on the 2nd screen.

I press the back button.

The images on my buttons do not show.

I can still press my 'invisible' buttons.

Why do my images not show?

My xaml:

```
        <Button BorderThickness="0" Name="btn4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Width="75" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <Button.Background >
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Number-4-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button BorderThickness="0" Name="btn5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="75" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <Button.Background >
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Number-5-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button BorderThickness="0" Name="btn6" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Width="75" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <Button.Background >
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Number-6-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>

        <Button BorderThickness="0" Name="btn7" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Width="75" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <Button.Background >
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Number-7-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button BorderThickness="0" Name="btn8" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Width="75" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <Button.Background >
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Number-8-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button BorderThickness="0" Name="btn9" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Width="75" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <Button.Background >
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Number-9-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>

        <Button  BorderThickness="0" Name="btnReset" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Width="75" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Padding="9.5,0,9.5,3.5" >
            <Button.Background  >
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Images/undo.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button  BorderThickness="0" Name="btn0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Width="75" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <Button.Background >
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Number-0-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button BorderThickness="0" Name="btnDel" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Width="75" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <Button.Background >
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/delete_key.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="Footer" Background="Black" Grid.Row="4" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Name="txtError" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="18" Margin="10,10,10,10" Text="Enter PIN" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFE8E82F" FontWeight="Bold"  />

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you show the code - especially for those buttons with images - how do you load images? There is a chance that your app was terminated and then restored.

Comment: @Romasz HI, i shal post the xaml..